# Can we create our own field in doxygen documentation?

Tags: c, doxygen

I am a noob to doxygen so please forgive if I am asking a basic question. I have gone through complete documentation but couldn't figure out a solution to this myself. Here's what I have in my code:

```
typedef struct{
  uint32_t event;
  void (*action)(void);
} CommandChain;

CommandChain commandRepo[] = {
  {.event = 0, .action = NULL},
  {.event = 1, .action = Start_Timer},
  {.event = 2, .action = Start_Gps}
}
```

Where action corresponds to the functions I have elsewhere defined. I need to create an XML output where I have a field of Event and a corresponding Action. I need it in a parseable format. Like: @event_id 2 @triggers Gps
So, I can check what event will trigger what action.

PS. I know '@' is used for the commands in doxygen, just using to make my point somehow clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see [doxygen's Custom Commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html):

> Here is an example of an alias definition with a single argument:
>
> `ALIASES += l{1}="\ref \1"`

The above adds support for a `@l` command with a single argument, which expands to `\ref \1` in the output, where `\1` is the argument text. I think you can use this to build what you need.